# non-existing attributes in getfeatureinfo when attribute value is empty

Tags: javascript, getfeatureinfo

I am trying to build a table in javascript from getfeatureinfo. I do this by this code:

```
function showInfo(evt) {
        var f = 0;
        var temstr = "";
        if(evt.features.length != 0){
            for (f = 0; f <= evt.features.length - 1; f++) {
                if(evt.features[f].gml.featureType == "amice_om_herk"){
                    temstr = temstr + "<b>" + "<center>Herkomstlocatie</center>" + "</b>";
                    temstr = temstr + "<table>";
                    temstr += "<tr>";
                    temstr = temstr += "<th>ID</th>" +  "<th>Houseletter</th>" +"<th>City</th>" +"<tr>";
                    for ( var key in evt.features[f].attributes) {
                        switch (key){
                        case 'afvlstrnum':
                            temstr += "<td>" 
                            + evt.features[f].attributes[key] + "</td>";
                            break;
                        case 'numtv_herk':
                            if (evt.features[f].attributes[key] != null){
                            temstr += "<td>"
                            + evt.features[f].attributes[key] + "</td>";
                            break;
                            }
                            else {
                                temstr += "<td></td>";
                                break;
                            }
                        case 'plts_herk':
                            if (evt.features[f].attributes[key] !== ""){
                            temstr += "<td>"
                            + evt.features[f].attributes[key] + "</td>";
                            break;
                            }
```

However, some attributes contain no value. In that case, the getfeatureinfo doesnt recognize the attribute name. So, when i build my table with  and one of the cases for that particular cell is without a value, it skips the case, moves on to the next one and fills the cell with attribute value which should be in the next column. An image of what goes wrong:

[image]

Is there a possibility fill `<td>` with something like 'nodata' or fill it with nothing? I tried to make an if statement (as seen in the code), but since it never comes into the `case` when, for that cell, the attribute name doesnt exist, this wont work.